# Is there a way to get an idea of complex integrals just by looking?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

If you see the graph of a function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, the area interpretation of the integral makes it easy to have a rough idea of what an integral is going to be. For example, I know that something like $\int_0^{10} x^2 dx$ is going to be very large, and I know that $\int_{-100}^{100} \sin x dx$ is going to be relatively small.

Is there a way to get a similar idea for integrals of functions $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ along contours? For example, do you have any idea what $\int_{\gamma} z^2 dz$ would be if $\gamma$ is the straight line from $-100+100i$ to $100+100i$?

I know the upper bound

$$\left| \int_{\gamma} f(z) dz \right| \le \sup_{z \in \gamma} |f(z)| \cdot \text{length}(\gamma)$$

but I imagine this is in general a bad estimate, and I don't know any lower bound.

Comment: $\int^{100}_{-100}\sin(x)dx=0$ because $\sin(x)$ is an odd function. Also, I don't understand how your bound for $\int_0^{10} x^2 dx$ is any better than the bound for complex integration at the end. Maybe you need to explain more what kind of lower bound is good in your opinion.  Also, shouldn't it instead be $$\bigg| \int_{\gamma} f(z) dz\bigg| \le \sup_{z \in \gamma} |f(z)| \cdot \text{length}(\gamma)$$ because the order of real numbers cannot be extended to an order on complex numbers?

Comment: @stressedout Yes sorry I forgot the absolute value in the inequality. Well what I mean is this: Compare $\int_0^{10} x^2 dx$ to $\int_{\gamma} z^2 dz$, where $\gamma$ is the path given in the question. For the real integral, I understand that it's very large. However, for this complex integral, I have no idea if its going to be large or small, and which direction it's going to point in. I have a suspicion that it's going to be large, but I'm not nearly as sure as I am with the real integral.

Comment: I think there's a problem with comparing real integrals to complex integrals. Consider an integral that its real part is zero but its complex part grows infinitely large. Then the above formula will given you an infinitely large value because it is trying to give you a bound for all complex inputs, while the real part doesn't grow at all. Also, as I showed in my example, the formula is really optimal in the sense that in general, we can't do better than that.

Comment: My suggestion would be to represent the complex-valued function in terms of its real and imaginary parts. You can then view the contour integration in terms of a line integral of two real-valued functions. This will presumably reduce to your intuition for integrals of functions of one real variable. As Doug M stated below, however, you will eventually gain intuition in terms of singularities and their residues.

Answer (score 1):

I think your bound should actually be given by

$$\bigg| \int_{\gamma} f(z) dz\bigg| \le \sup_{z \in \gamma} |f(z)| \cdot \text{length}(\gamma)$$

If so, then you can't give a better bound in general. Just take $f(z)= \overline{z}$ and let $\gamma: [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ be given by $\gamma(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$, i.e. the parametrization of the unit circle.

Then $\sup_{z \in \gamma} |f(z)|=1$, $\text{length}(\gamma)=2\pi$ and the integral in the LHS is $2\pi i$. So, the inequality becomes an equality for $f(z)=\overline{z}$ showing that a lower bound that works for all functions is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Complex integrals do not have an immediate geometric analogue as integrals in single variable calculus do.

Nonetheless, there are some things that you will learn to how to see.

If your function is holomorphic

$\oint_\gamma f(z)\ dz = 0$

Holomorphic is a little bit like continuous and differentiable.  However, it must also satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  Most of your favorite functions are holopmorphic  -- polynomials, exponentials, sine, cosine.

If your function fails to to be holomorphic at finitely many points.  Then we can evaluate the integral by evaluating just the points where it fails.

For example, $f(z) = \frac 1z$

This function fails at the origin and only at that one point.

This means that any closed contour that contains the origin will have the same contour integral.  So, in time you will learn to identify these points, and to evaluate these points.